# Azure function written in java throws FailureException: OutOfMemoryError: Java heap spaceStack while unzipping file size > 80MB

Tags: java, unzip, azure-blob-storage, azure-function-app, azure-blob-trigger

I have an Azure function written in java, which will listen to a queue message on azure, queue message has path to zip file on azure blob container, once the queue message is received it take zip file from the path location on azure and unzips to a container on azure. It works fine for small size files but > 80 MB it shows `FailureException: OutOfMemoryError: Java heap spaceStack`  exception. My code is as below

```
@FunctionName("queueprocessor")
public void run(@QueueTrigger(name = "msg",
                              queueName = "queuetest",
                              dataType = "",
                              connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage") Details message,
                final ExecutionContext executionContext,
                @BlobInput(name = "file", 
                           dataType = "binary", 
                           connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage",
                           path = "{Path}") byte[] content) {

  executionContext.getLogger().info("PATH: " + message.getPath());

  CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = null;
  CloudBlobClient blobClient = null;
  CloudBlobContainer container = null;

  try {

    String connectStr = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=name;AccountKey=mykey;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";

    //unique name of the container
    String containerName = "output";

    // Config to upload file size > 1MB in chunks
    int deltaBackoff = 2;
    int maxAttempts = 2;
    BlobRequestOptions blobReqOption = new BlobRequestOptions();
    blobReqOption.setSingleBlobPutThresholdInBytes(1024 * 1024); // 1MB
    blobReqOption.setRetryPolicyFactory(new RetryExponentialRetry(deltaBackoff, maxAttempts));

    // Parse the connection string and create a blob client to interact with Blob storage
    storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.parse(connectStr);
    blobClient = storageAccount.createCloudBlobClient();
    blobClient.setDefaultRequestOptions(blobReqOption);
    container = blobClient.getContainerReference(containerName);

    container.createIfNotExists(BlobContainerPublicAccessType.CONTAINER, new BlobRequestOptions(), new OperationContext());

    ZipInputStream zipIn = new ZipInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(content));

    ZipEntry zipEntry = zipIn.getNextEntry();
    while (zipEntry != null) {
      executionContext.getLogger().info("ZipEntry name: " + zipEntry.getName());

      //Getting a blob reference
      CloudBlockBlob blob = container.getBlockBlobReference(zipEntry.getName());

      ByteArrayOutputStream outputB = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
      int n;
      while ((n = zipIn.read(buf, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
        outputB.write(buf, 0, n);
      }

      // Upload to container
      ByteArrayInputStream inputS = new ByteArrayInputStream(outputB.toByteArray());

      blob.setStreamWriteSizeInBytes(256 * 1024); // 256K

      blob.upload(inputS, inputS.available());

      executionContext.getLogger().info("ZipEntry name: " + zipEntry.getName() + " extracted");
      zipIn.closeEntry();
      zipEntry = zipIn.getNextEntry();
    }
    zipIn.close();

    executionContext.getLogger().info("FILE EXTRACTION FINISHED");

  } catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

`Details message` has ID and file path, path is given as input to `@BlobInput(..., path ={Path},...)`. According to my analysis I feel `@BlobInput` is loading full file into memory that's why I am getting `OutOfMemoryError`. If I'm right please let me know any other way to avoid it ?. Because in future file size might go up to 2GB. In case any mistake in unzipping code please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: You hold both the zip file (in `content`) and the unzipped file (in `outputB`) fully in memory at the same time. I don't know if there's a way for you to get `content` as a stream, but at least the unzipped file itself you should be able to just straight up stream and not unpack fully (assuming CloudBlockBlob can actually consume a stream without fully loading it into memory).

Comment: Thank you, I just managed to get ```content``` directly from URL stream and it worked.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Could you please post your suggestions as a solution? It may help more people who have similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I summarize @JoachimSauer's suggestion as below.

When we use Azure Function blob storage binding to process Azure blob content in java function application, it will hold the whole content in memory. Using it to process large size files,  we may face  `OutOfMemoryError`. So If we want to process large size azure blob, we should use the blob sdk to open an input stream then process content with the stream.

For example

SDK

```
    <dependency>
          <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
          <artifactId>azure-storage-blob</artifactId>
          <version>12.9.0</version>
      </dependency>
```

Code

```
 String accountName="";
        String accountKey="";
        StorageSharedKeyCredential sharedKeyCredential =
                new StorageSharedKeyCredential(accountName, accountKey);

        BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder()
                               .credential(sharedKeyCredential)
                               .endpoint("https://" + accountName + ".blob.core.windows.net")
                               .buildClient();
        BlobContainerClient desContainerClient = blobServiceClient.getBlobContainerClient("output");
        BlobContainerClient sourceContainerClient = blobServiceClient.getBlobContainerClient("upload");
        BlobInputStreamOptions option = new BlobInputStreamOptions();
        //The size of each data chunk returned from the service
        option.setBlockSize(1024*1024);
        ZipInputStream zipInput = null;
        try {

            zipInput= new ZipInputStream( sourceContainerClient.getBlobClient("<read file name deom queue message>").openInputStream(option));
            ZipEntry zipEntry= zipInput.getNextEntry();
            while(zipEntry != null){
                System.out.println("ZipEntry name: " + zipEntry.getName());
                BlobOutputStream outputB = desContainerClient.getBlobClient(zipEntry.getName()).getBlockBlobClient().getBlobOutputStream();
                byte[] bytesIn = new byte[1024*1024];
                int read = 0;
                while ((read = zipInput.read(bytesIn)) != -1) {
                    outputB.write(bytesIn, 0, read);
                }
                outputB.flush();
                outputB.close();
                zipInput.closeEntry();
                zipEntry =zipInput.getNextEntry();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            try {
                zipInput.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

[image]
[image]

For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=csharp#concurrency-and-memory-usage).

Comment: thank you for the whole code. can you please tell me what was the file size you tried and what was the Heap size on azure or local machine.

Comment: @brijeshPatil My zip file is 189MB. In my test environment, the InitialHeapSize is  134217728 and the MaxHeapSize is 2118123520.

Comment: i need to test this on azure environment. because heap size is very less on azure, will test it then will surely accept it.